# How can I compute T2 Hotelling after PCA?

Tags: r, pca

I need to compute Hotelling T2 and SPE (Q), after the PCA analysis. I did it using the pca function from library mdatools, but I see the PC computed are different from the one computed by prcomp or princomp functions. Why?

```
library(mdatools)
NF4.3.pca4 <- pca(NF4.3, ncomp = 15, center = T, scale = T)
res <- NF4.3.pca4$calres

NF4.3.pca <- prcomp(NF4.3, center = T, scale. = T) #different eigenvalues
```

Is there another way to calculate T2 and SPE from principal components?

Data:

```
ASSORB_CAT1;ASSORB_CAT3;ASSORB_VOLANO;AZOTO_IN
0.03662109;23.55957;-12.30469;39.3
0;25.36621;-11.09619;39.2
-0.02441406;21.92383;-11.26709;39.2
-0.02441406;23.10791;-11.07178;39.1
-0.04882813;22.81494;-10.57129;39.59975
0;24.24316;-11.23047;39.89737
0;22.63184;-11.43799;39.8
-0.04882813;24.34082;-13.61084;39.5
0;21.83838;-11.1084;39.4
0;24.3042;-12.08496;39.3
0;24.67041;-12.40234;39.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain on an other dataset, as I do not have access to what you are analysing. The two methods that you applied on my dataset are identical. What can be confusing though is that if you look at `stats_pca$sdev` it is **a root square** of the vector of eigenvalues, whereas `mdatools_pca$eigenvals` reports eigenvalues themselves.

```
library(mdatools)
data("mtcars")
stats_pca <- prcomp(mtcars, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
mdatools_pca <- mdatools::pca(mtcars, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

all.equal(sqrt(mdatools_pca$eigenvals)[1:length(stats_pca$sdev)], stats_pca$sdev)
# TRUE
```

If you want to go on with Hotelling's T2 I would recommend this read: [PCA and Hotelling's T^2 for confidence intervall in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637860/pca-and-hotellings-t2-for-confidence-intervall-in-r).

Comment: I see  "Mean relative difference: 0.3862249"   with my data

Comment: I've made some investigation and it seems that it is not your fault. Implementation in the `mdatools` library has (probably) a defect with scaling. If a column has a negative mean (as is in your case 2 columns have) it is not scaled. That is why the values differ. You can either disable scaling or provide precomputed vector of standard deviations in `pca` function to get identical results as in `prcomp`. I opened an issue on that error: https://github.com/svkucheryavski/mdatools/issues/59.